# Why aren't my photos synchronizing?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, photos, data-synchronization

They stopped syncing recently.  I called Apple support and they had me update both my iPhone 6 and my Macbook Air which I did.

I verified that the settings are correct.

[image]

I also verified that both devices are connected to the internet.

What else can I check?

Comment: Just to clarify, the photos you click on your iPhone are not visible in photos.app right?

Comment: I have both a photos app on my iPhone and a photos app on my macBook Air.  The photos on my iPhone are not showing up on my macBook Air in the photos app like they should.

Comment: At the bottom of the iPhone photos app, in photos tab, see if the photos has been synced. Also in iCloud.com, Please check and confirm if the photos has been uploaded. Then we might isolate macbook

Comment: Magically started working when I looked in the Photos tab in ... the Photos app.  I recently have been using QuickTime to watch movies and I noticed that iCloud was configured to save "QuickTime files".  I don't know if this means it was trying to upload movies I watched to the cloud, but maybe that was jamming up my network ... I don't know.

Comment: I did recently configure iCloud not to synch QuickTime.  Don't know if that fixed it.

Comment: Glad it helped. Also, wifi and cellular are also some factors in play sometimes. And low power mode too. Also plug into power to speed up face recognition in the app. So many things to remember.

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of the iPhone photos app, in photos tab, see if the photos has been synced. Also in iCloud.com, Please check and confirm if the photos has been uploaded.

Maybe other uploads are jamming the networks. As mentioned in the comments, Quicktime files are doing so